# How to automatically sign commits with magit?

Tags: magit, git, security, gpg

I'm interested on having each of my commits signed with my GPG key. Since I use magit for interfacing with git, I was wondering if telling magit to sign each commit was possible (or some workaround to achieve this was feasible, at least).

Comment: Does Git even support commit signing?  I thought only tags could be signed…

Comment: @lunaryorn `git commit -S[<keyid>], --gpg-sign[=<keyid>]`. There is at least one reason to sign each commit: to have stronger evidence that the commit came from the person you think it did. Signing tags only allows you to detect history changes.

Comment: @Nsukami_That does not answer my question, does it?

Comment: @lunaryorn Sorry if it doesn't answer your question. Yes, Git support [commit signing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work#Signing-Commits)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Magit commits are created using the committing popup (<kbd>c</kbd>). That popup would therefore be a good place to start looking for gpg support. If you do that, then you will find this:

```
=S Sign using gpg (--gpg-sign=)
```

So type <kbd>= S</kbd> and the select a key. To avoid having to do that every time you create a commit you can save the value of that argument (and all other currently set arguments) using <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>.

You might still have to type the passphrase every time. To avoid that you should start a gpg-agent and make sure Emacs knows about it, e.g. using the `keychain` shell script and the `keychain-environment` Emacs package.

Also see and set the `--show-signature` argument in the logging popup.

Comment: Has this been changed in `transient`?

Comment: This argument is now hidden by default. The transient announcement explains how to show it by changing the "level".

Comment: In case anyone stumbles here looking: https://magit.vc/manual/transient/Enabling-and-Disabling-Suffixes.html

Comment: @tarsius I don't seem to be able to change the level. How do I set about doing that? Thank you.

Comment: Which part of the documentation that tejasbubane linked to is unclear?

Answer (score 24):

Try this in your `$HOME/.gitconfig` or your `.git/config`

```
[user]
    email = YourEmail
    name = YourName
    signingkey = XXXXXXXX
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

Then just commit as usual.

Comment: This answer has the advantage that you can set a key per repository. It seems that magit's `=S` option sets the key in `$HOME/.gitconfig`, so the same for all your repositories.